# Java User Interface Improvement

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, error-handling, user-input

I have been trying to present this a little better to the user. I am trying to setup if he puts in the wrong input then he has to start over until he puts in the right numbers set between 0 and 9000. Its also an multiplication iteration and a recursion. But I am not sure why the messages I setup are not displaying when he makes an error. Got any idea why and improvement ideas, got any code examples?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multiplication {

public static int multIterative(int a, int b) {

    int result = 0;

    while (b > 0) {

        result += a;
        b--;
    }
    return result;
}

public static int multRecursive(int a, int b) {

    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {

        return 0;
    }

    return a + multRecursive(a, b - 1);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        System.out.print("Please enter first Integer: ");
        System.out.print("Please enter second Integer: ");

        try {

            a = userInput.nextInt();
            b = userInput.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println("Must enter an integer!");
            userInput.next();

        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {

            System.out.println("Thats too much");
            userInput.next();

        }

    } while (a >= 9000 || b >= 9000);

    System.out.println("The Multiplication Iteration would be: "
            + multIterative(a, b));

    System.out.println("The Multiplication Recursion would be: "
            + multRecursive(a, b));

}
}
```

Comment: also I am not sure why the numbers are going under the printed message

Comment: Post a sample input and corresponding output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Integer.parseInt(...)` instead and checking for `NumberFormatException`.

Following do-while works:

```
do
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter first Integer: ");
            a = Integer.parseInt(userInput.next());
            System.out.print("Please enter second Integer: ");
            b = Integer.parseInt(userInput.next());
            if (a >= 9000 || b >= 9000)
                throw new StackOverflowError();
            break;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            System.out.println("Must enter an integer!");

        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {

            System.out.println("Thats too much");

        }
    while (true);
```

Comment: that's actually a lot different then what I had though of.

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters a value bigger then `9000` no error will the thrown so your `"Thats too much"` message will never be shown, to show that message you will have to perform a check like this:

```
if(a >= 9000 || b >= 9000){
   System.out.println("Thats too much");
}
```